# Performing string operations on data that might contain null \0

Tags: c++, string, null

I'm implementing a pluggable MIME filter for IE (this question concerns `IInternetProtocol::Read(void*, ULONG, ULONG*)`) and I'm intercepting incoming HTML with a view to modify the HTML.

The HTML is *generally* UTF-8 encoded, except there are some `\0` (null) characters, and sits inside a `char` buffer. I want to load it inside a `std::string` instance so I can perform string operations such as `std::string::find` as well as inserting content (by copying substrings into a destination buffer around my injected string, something like this:

```
string received( this->buffer );
size_t index = received.find("<p id=\"foo\">");
if( index != string::npos ) {

    memcpy( destination             , received              , index );
    memcpy( destination + index     , "Injected content"    ,    17 );
    memcpy( destination + index + 17, received.substr(index), received.size() - 17 - index );
} else {
    memcpy( destination             , this->buffer          , this->bufferSize );
}
```

The problem is that the buffer might contain null bytes (it's a quirk of the website I'm working with). To what extent would `\0` character values interact with the string operations such as `find`? The documentation on MSDN nor CPlusPlus.com does not say.

Comment: If the text received is pure text and [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded, then it should not really contain any zero bytes.If it does then the text is not UTF-8. And while `std::string` can store data with embedded zeroes (but you have to use another [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) where you specify the length) I'm not so sure you can really treat it as a string then and use the normal string operations.

Comment: By the way, it's easy to try yourself:  http://ideone.com/AdRNm8

Comment: The `std::string` functions shouldn't care about what characters are in the string - I'm not sure the standard says so, but in my experience, NUL characters in a string has no effect, except for when you use `c_str`.